# Is there another way to link on same page

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I have a link which opens a table on the same page if user clicks on the link. What I want to know is that is there another way to link on the same page rather than doing this:

```
<a href="#" id="showGrid">[Open Grid]</a>
```

This is because in the url it displays # at the end of the url so I want to know is there another way to link on the same page than href="#".

Thanks

Comment: I don´t understand de question. Why you don´t use the href for setting the url that you want go?

Comment: @josegil I suppose that user1050384 uses javascript to catch the click event on this link and do some work

Comment: Because if I set it to the same url by typing in the url, it would not open up the table

Comment: Is it possible to use `href="."`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why even use an `<a>` tag if you are just binding an event handler to the element.  Just use a `<span>` and style it.  You can even give it *cursor:pointer* if you want that link feel/look

Comment: using `a` tag, makes the element focusable, so it can be easily accessed on the mobile devices

Comment: ok with that in mind, then I think as has already been suggested, try returning false from your event handler.

Comment: Hi, you are right I don't need to use <a>, I can use <span. and then use css to style it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just return false in javascript and the link will not be followed when clicked, but you can still open your tables using js, as i suspect you do right now

Comment: Where do I put the return false, do I create a new function? If you need to see the javascript code then tell me and I will post js code

Comment: it should be the last line in your event handler function

Comment: I guess what you do is handle the click event and open the table, in the handler function just make the last line "return false;" which will prevent following the link

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you alread have some function binded to the click event of this link, right? if so you can just use `href="javascript:void(0)"`, this way is much better, because in this case browser doesn't add a context menu items such as "Open link in new tab" or "Copy link address" to this link.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Javascript to detect when an element is clicked, you don't have to use tha anchor tag, or the href attribute.

You could do `<a id="showGrid">Open Grid</a>` and then something like `$('a#showGrid').click(...);` if using jQuery. To get the "link cursor" you can do `a {cursor: pointer}` in CSS. It'll look the same, but you won't get that # in the browser's address bar.

Comment: if you don't add a href attribute to the `a` tag, if will not be rendered as a link, and maybe our college want to see it as a link